# Move div in div with position "relative" not working

Tags: html, css

I´m trying to desing a rabbit in css, but the divs in my main parent div aren't moving if I e.g. type "top: 20%"

The parent div is in position "relative" right now. I tried differend position attributes.

```
.rabbit{
    --rabbit-skin: #965d00;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: white;
}

.rabbit-bottom{
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 75%;
    background: var(--rabbit-skin);
    border-radius: 50% 50% 40% 40%;
}
```

So I want the rabbit bottom to move. It's my main background for rabbits lower part. But it just flows to the upper right corner.

Comment: If you added `position:absolute` to rabbit-bottom, would that solve your problem?
It is really hard to visualise the issue and suggest a solution without seeing the HTML part of the code. Please provide that - preferably in a snippet that is directly viewable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` if you are to position `.rabbit-bottom` relative to `.rabbit`

```css
.rabbit {
  --rabbit-skin: #965d00;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
}

.rabbit-bottom {
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 75%;
  background: var(--rabbit-skin);
  border-radius: 50% 50% 40% 40%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="rabbit">
  <div class="rabbit-bottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I missed the "position: absolute" part. Now it works. Thank you